# Link within content, background fill left to right, and then right to left so it looks like the box is sliding right through

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, linear-gradients

I am trying to carry out an animation on links, the background should fill from left to right, and then the background should reverse and go from right to left. I have created a Pen for the first part:

```css
p {
  color: #000;
}

a {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #903e77 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-position: left bottom;
  transition: background 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence with a <a href="#">link</a> in the middle.</p>
```

I am thinking this needs a span element or something inside to act as another background block.

The effect would be similar to links here:

https://ueno.co/contact

In the footer is most noticeable.

Comment: They're using additional jquery scripts

Comment: Yes I don't want to reproduce it exactly. And if possible I wish to use pure CSS. Might not be possible as it may require js to add/remove classes on hover and hover out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust it like this:

```css
p {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  background: linear-gradient(#903e77, #903e77);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 200% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-position: -100% 0;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence with a <a href="">link</a> in the middle.</p>
```

Or like this:

```css
p {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  background: linear-gradient(#903e77, #903e77);
  background-size: 0 100%;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-size 0.5s,background-position 0s 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:right;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence with a <a href="">link</a> in the middle.</p>
```

Also like this:

```css
p {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  background: linear-gradient(#903e77, #903e77);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 200% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition:background-position 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  background-position: -100% 0;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence with a <a href="">link</a> in the middle.</p>
```

Comment: The 'link' could/should be highlighted.

Comment: @Viira didn't understand what you mean

Comment: I suggest that link could be highlighted to show that it was really a **LINK**. I can't phrase my expressions in a sentence.

Comment: A fantastic answer, I have been testing this and it works across the whole site. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positioned pseudo-element on the link and manipulate the position of that with a `transform`

```css
p {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2em;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

a:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<p>This is a sentence with a <a href="">link</a> in the middle.</p>
```